# I have a dictionary of dataframes. I need a merged dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dictionary of data frames. The code reads ticker through a list and fetches Open High Low Close and Volume then adds a column with ticker name. All non required columns are dropped. This is undertaken for all items in list and stores in a dictionary. Here is the code..

```
dataframe_collection = {}
for i in range(0,len(list)):
   i=list[i]
   ohlc = fetchOHLC(i, "day", 5)
   ohlc['base'] = ohlc.close / ohlc.close[0]
   ohlc.rename(columns={'base': i}, inplace=True)
   # Drop un-required columns
   ohlc.drop(ohlc.iloc[:, 0:5], axis=1, inplace=True)
   dataframe_collection[i]= ohlc
```

Each dataframe has same index. I intend to create a common data frame merged such that dataframe should look like this

```
date                         ACC            HINDUNILVR           LT   
2021-08-26 00:00:00+05:30    1.000000       1.000000            1.000000
2021-08-27 00:00:00+05:30    1.031882       1.004332            1.026539    
2021-08-30 00:00:00+05:30    1.048757       1.007988            1.040326
2021-08-31 00:00:00+05:30    1.057810       1.020102            1.020102
.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope having solved your matter :

```
#convert your dictionnary to a list
list_dataframes = dataframe_collection.values()
#keep the dictionnary keys with the same order, in case you will need them
list_dataframes_keys = dataframe_collection.keys()

#if the date is not the index
df = pd.concat([x.set_index('date') for x in list_dataframes], axis=1)
#if the date is the index
df = pd.concat([x for x in list_dataframes], axis=1)
```

Edit :

On one line code as suggested by @chris :

```
pd.concat([v.set_index('date') for k,v in dataframe_collection.items()], axis=1)
```

Comment: `pd.concat([v.set_index('date') for k,v in dataframe_collection.items()], axis=1)`

Comment: Chris many thanks for your response. I am getting a following error.                   KeyError: "None of ['date'] are in the columns"

Comment: Thanks Issam that is working like a charm ... Many thanks for you super quick help.

Comment: @Chris suggestion is giving following error. KeyError: "None of ['date'] are in the columns"

Comment: @ANen In your case, use this instead  `pd.concat([v for k,v in dataframe_collection.items()], axis=1)`

Comment: That is working perfectly. Many thanks Issam and @Chris